# Need update statement for Oracle updating any value to its current

Tags: database, oracle, rdbms

I need to check if database is in read only mode. The best way I see is to make a fake update e.g. updating one row setting some column value to its current. How can I make such a statement?

Comment: Why is that better than checking with `select open_mode from v$database` ?

Comment: @Alex Poole The user the application uses to connect to database doesn't have such privileges to even see the `v$database` table

Answer (score 0):

Well, it appeared to be much more easier than it seemed to me. In case one need a solution this is it:

```
update SOME_TABLE set SOME_COLUMN = SOME_COLUMN where rownum = 1
```